# Multiply and add elements in 2 arrays

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 arrays say `arrayA` & `arrayB`. `arrayA` has the elements say [1,2] and `arrayB` has the elements say [3,4]. Now I want to multiply and add the elements in these arrays like so.. 1x3 + 2x4 = 11. How can I achieve this...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here a combo of zip, map and reduce:

```
let result = (zip([1,2], [3,4]).map { $0.0 * $0.1 }).reduce(0, +)
print(result) // 11
```

---

1. [Zip](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip) makes a sequence of pairs based on the two arrays: `(1,3), (2,4)`
2. with `map` I am iterating for each element of the array producing at each iteration a new element
3. `$0` means the element of the sequence at the current iteration. Since the element is a pair (because of zip), we can access to the first sub-element of the pair with $0.0 and to the second with $0.1.
4. finally (after `map`) we get an array of products, just need to "reduce" it to a number, summing all the resulting elements with `reduce`.
5. (0, +) means that `reduce` starts from `0` as initial value, then with the abbreviation `+` we can accumulate the sums of all the elements.

Comment: Thanks @Andrea Mugnaini

Comment: .@Andrea Mugnaini Would you mind explaining a bit as to how the above code works. I mean what does 0.1,0.0, reduce etc. stand for...?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andrea Mugnaini...:)It was helpful! Also does zip take 2 arrays only & not more or less it..?

Comment: @v.bw zip takes two arrays and if they don't have the same dimension, the result is a sequence with dimension = `min(a.count,b.count)`

Comment: Amazing. @AndreaMugnaini

Comment: With the current Swift you can shorten this to `zip([1,2], [3,4]).map(*).reduce(0, +)`

Answer (score 2):

Note that rather than using a chained `map` and `reduce` (for multiplication and summation, respectively), you could directly apply the `reduce` operation on the zipped sequence, and modify the `reduce` closure to accordingly calculate the sum of the pair-wise multiplied objects in the zipped sequence:

```
let a = [1, 2]
let b = [3, 4]

let result = zip(a,b).reduce(0) { $0 + $1.0 * $1.1 } // 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
let A = [1,2]
let B = [3,4]

let C = zip(A, B).map {$0.0 * $0.1}

print(C) // [3, 8]

let sum = C.reduce(0, +)

print(sum)//11
```

Comment: When I tried something like `let c = zip(sellingPriceArray, quantityArray).map { *}` But it gives the error `Expected expression after unary operator`

Comment: @v.bw- Try again.